# JSF 2.0 Fields aren't cleared the second time user opens dialog

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, refresh, field

I don't know if it is a common problem, but this strange problem is giving me some headache...
I'm having an strange behavior, my application has a lot of dialogs, and when user opens one, the dialog should show default content. The problem is that I clear all bean's properties before show the dialog, but sometimes it appears that the form isn't cleared!!
For example, this is one of the dialogs that are having this problem:

[image: how it should be]
This image show how the dialog appears the first time I open it, all fields are cleared and the second radio is selected. If I change the radio selection and enter something in the input field, the datatable immediately shows the data accordingly with the search. So, if I click in "Cancelar" (cancel in portuguese), this dialog is closed, like expected.

Then I open this dialog again and:

[image: how it is shown after oppened after cancel action]
The fields store the last edition user made. I thought I wasn't clearing the bean, but if I just press F5 (refresh) the dialog is shown like in the first image. I don't know why, but some fields aren't updated!!

My dialogs are created using this template:

```
<ui:component>
<hrgi:popup id="#{idPopup}" titulo="#{titulo}" renderizar="#{popup.visivel}"
            bordaConteudo="#{bordaConteudo eq null?true:bordaConteudo}">
    <f:facet name="cabecalho">
        <ui:insert name="cabecalho"></ui:insert>
    </f:facet>
    <f:facet name="conteudo">
        <h:panelGroup id="#{idPopup}Conteudo" layout="block" style="width:100%">
            <p:focus/>
            <ui:insert name="conteudo">Nenhum conteúdo definido!</ui:insert>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </f:facet>
    <f:facet name="botoes">
        <h:panelGroup style="width:100%">
            <h:panelGrid id="#{idPopup}PainelMensagens" style="width:100%">
                <p:messages/>
            </h:panelGrid>
            <ui:insert name="barraDeBotoes">
                <h:panelGroup layout="block" style="width:100%">
                    <p:commandButton value="CANCELAR" styleClass="hrgi-botao-popup"
                                     immediate="true" update="@form"
                                     action="#{controladorPopup.fechar}"/>
                    <p:commandButton value="OK" styleClass="hrgi-botao-popup"
                                     action="#{controladorPopup.submit}" update="@form alerta #{atualizar}">
                        <f:param name="REQUIRED" value="true"/>
                    </p:commandButton>
                </h:panelGroup>
            </ui:insert>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </f:facet>
</hrgi:popup>
</ui:component>
```

The dialog shown in the print is created this way:

```
<ui:composition template="../templates/popupSubmit.xhtml">
<ui:param name="titulo" value="#{cadastroMsg['popup.cadastro.listagem_empresa.titulo']}" />
<ui:param name="popup" value="#{modeloPopupBuscaEmpresa}" />
<ui:param name="controladorPopup" value="#{controladorPopupBuscaEmpresa}" />
<ui:define name="conteudo">
    <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="hrgi-div-form clearfix">
        <hrgi:listagem listenerBusca="#{controladorListagemEmpresa}"
                       valorBusca="#{modeloListagemEmpresa.valorBusca}">
            <f:facet name="filtrosAdicionais">
                <h:panelGroup layout="block">
                    <h:outputText value="#{msgGerais['gerais.listagem.filtro']}"/>
                    <h:selectOneRadio value="#{modeloListagemEmpresa.tipoFiltro}" immediate="true">
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="CNPJ" itemValue="0"/>
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Apelido" itemValue="1"/>
                        <f:ajax event="change" immediate="true"
                                render="tabelaListagem"
                                listener="#{controladorListagemEmpresa.atualizarTipoFiltro}"/>
                    </h:selectOneRadio>
                </h:panelGroup>
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="tabela">
                <h:panelGroup layout="block" style="height: 219px; width: 103%">
                    <p:dataTable value="#{modeloListagemEmpresa.itens}"
                                 scrollable="true" height="194" var="empresa"
                                 emptyMessage="#{msgGerais['gerais.sem_dados']}"
                                 selectionMode="single" onRowUnselectUpdate="painelInformacoes"
                                 selection="#{modeloListagemEmpresa.itemSelecionado}"
                                 onRowSelectUpdate="painelInformacoes">
                        <p:column style="width:20%"
                                  headerText="Documento">
                            <h:outputText value="#{empresa.cnpj}"/>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column style="width:80%"
                                  headerText="Apelido">
                            <h:outputText value="#{empresa.nomeEmpresa}"/>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:dataTable>
                </h:panelGroup>
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="informacoes">
                <ui:include src="../../outros/painelInformacoesBasicasEmpresa.xhtml">
                    <ui:param name="modeloPopup" value="#{modeloListagemEmpresa}"/>
                    <ui:param name="pessoaSelecionada" value="#{controladorListagemEmpresa.pessoaSelecionada}"/>
                </ui:include>
            </f:facet>
        </hrgi:listagem>
        <p:messages/>
    </h:panelGroup>
</ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

if I change the template code of "Cancelar" button, just removing immediate=true it works fine:

```
<p:commandButton value="CANCELAR" styleClass="hrgi-botao-popup"
                                     update="@form"
                                     action="#{controladorPopup.fechar}"/>
```

but in others dialog I have fields that are required and need validation...
Could someone explain me why is it happening??

Comment: The snippet you have posted doesn't contain the most interesting part - the definition of the actual fields containing values. I guess they are hidden behind `<ui:insert>`. What we can see here is basically the markup for the popup and the buttons - everything static.

Comment: @GrzegorzOledzki, I added more information :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this problem with the first approach [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MYFACES/Clear+Input+Components)

So I've created a method cancelar:

```
 public void cancelar(){
    fechar();
    //Limpa todos os campos do formulário
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    Application application = context.getApplication();
    ViewHandler viewHandler = application.getViewHandler();
    UIViewRoot viewRoot = viewHandler.createView(context, context
            .getViewRoot().getViewId());
    context.setViewRoot(viewRoot);
    context.renderResponse();
}
```

now button cancelar works this way:

```
<p:commandButton value="CANCELAR" styleClass="hrgi-botao-popup"
    update="@form" immediate="true" action="#{controladorPopup.cancelar}"/>
```